# Android- Not getting any push notifications after reboot

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Im trying to deal with android GCM and so far, Ive done this:
In my manifest:

```
<receiver
            android:name="service.GCMReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action  android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.android.myWatch" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

In my GCMReceiver class ( no need to put it all here, it wont contribute much )

```
public class GCMReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private String registration_id;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
         .......
    }
}
```

How I register  to gcm service:

```
Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
                registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(v.getContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0));
                registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", SENDER_ID);
                startService(registrationIntent);
```

If since last phone reboot I have opened the app and then closed / minimized it, the application will receive the intent with the pushed notification data, but when i will reboot my device i will stop receiving new notifications. What is missing?

I want that after i reboot, it will accumulate and process all of the intents that i missed meanwhile.

Comment: That will probably depend on how you did implement your third-party server and how you manage messages. However, when a message is sent to you and your app is not running, whenever it should be running and you connect to the `GCM` server they should be delivered to you (at most a short time after).

Comment: @nKn how is it related to my server? the whole point is that it sends and forgets about it, and the GCM servers will handle it, isnt it? I currently test my GCM behavior in my client by sending simple POST messages to GCM servers, not really embedded in my server yet. What should I do in order to receive messages after reboot?